# How to convert Matlab simulation code to R

Tags: r, matlab, simulation

I have been trying to to covert my following Matlabe code to R. I have tried but getting some errors.

**Matlab code**

```
S =100;K = 110; r = 0.05; sigma = 0.142470; dt = 1/365;
etime = 365; 
T = dt*etime; mean=0;var=1;
a=dt*(r-(.5*(sigma^2)));b=sqrt(dt)*sigma; lmax=1000; 
temp=0;
 for m=1:lmax
  x(1)=log(S);
   for n=1:etime
      x(n+1)=x(n)+a+b*normrnd(mean,var);
   end
  temp=temp+max(exp(x(etime+1))-K,0);
end
BS=(temp/lmax)*exp(-r*T)
```

Equivalent **R code** that I am trying:

```
S <- 100
K <- 110
r <- 0.05
sigma <- 0.142470
dt <- 1/365
etime <- 365
T <- dt*etime
mean <- 0
var <- 1
a <- dt*(r - (.5*(sigma^2)))
b <- sqrt(dt)*sigma
lmax <- 1000
temp <- 0
x <- 0

for (count in 1:lmax) {
  x[1] <- log(S)
  for (n in 1:etime) {
    x[n + 1] <- x[n] + a + b*rnorm(1, mean, var)
    temp <- temp + max(exp(x[etime + 1]) - K, 0)
  }
}

BS <- (temp/lmax)*exp(-r*T)
```

I am getting error on **temp** value. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't use `T` as an object name since in R it's an alias for `TRUE`.

Comment: Well noted @jsy.sf

Comment: ˋtempˋ  should be in the outer loop

Comment: Hi @MarBlo, Yes, you are right. temp should be in the outer loop. Now, It works nice I guess.